# Power Query in Bulk

Tags: excel, automation, powerquery

I have a Power Query that's been generated to transform a bunch of data in Excel. I now need to apply this query across ~400 excel files. I'm trying to leverage some automation to complete this task rather than applying the query to each file manually. I have 3 questions if anyone is able to assist:

1. The files have numerous tabs. A "Master" and then a tab for each month of the year. Is there a way to specify which tab to be used within the query?
2. Likely related to the question above, each tab is just text entered into the worksheet, there are no tables. Is there a way to automate having a table added based on the correct tab selection, to then run the query?
3. Is there a way to execute this Power Query across all ~400 files in bulk, as opposed to opening each one individually and pasting the query

Thanks

Comment: have you used google to search this issue ever ?  [How To Import Multiple Files With Multiple Sheets In Power Query](https://www.howtoexcel.org/how-to-import-multiple-files-with-multiple-sheets-in-power-query/)

Comment: Yes for all three questions. But, as @UmutK said, you have to post here your efforts to start coding it.

Comment: I did try, yes. Sorry, I know it seems like I've made no effort but I did spend some time on google and Power Automate before reaching out on here. Appreciate you guys taking the time. Thanks